# Restructuring Atlassian tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I just noticed that there is a tag [atlassian](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/atlassian) which doesn't really servera purpose, since Atlassian isn't a single product, they produce a lot of products. There are tags for some products:

- [fisheye](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fisheye): 10 questions
- [jira](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/jira): 85 questions
- [confluence](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/confluence): 45 questions
- [crowd](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/crowd): 8 questions

Usually tags like this start with the company name, like [microsoft-excel](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel) or [google-compute-engine](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/google-compute-engine), so I was about to start replacing these tags with [atlassian-fisheye](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/atlassian-fisheye) and similar tags, when I realized that it would most probably be much easier to just rename those tags.

Could someone with enough reputation just rename these tags?

Afterwards I would start retagging the remaining 41 questions just tagged with [atlassian](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/atlassian) with tags that refer to the actual product and write up some descriptions for those tags.

Comment: I'm not convinced these need to be renamed. They're recognizable brands on their own, and Atlassian might sell them on to some other company in the future. And you don't need to wait for them to be renamed to retag them anyway.

Comment: It could refer to a subset of Atlassian products, for instance integrating Crowd with Jira/Bitbucket/Confluence. So Atlassian could be a viable tag. Atlassian has an history of buying other products. So I agree with Michael.